# Is there a good way to extract chunks of data from a java 8 stream?

Tags: parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I an ETL process I'm retrieving a lot of entities from a Spring Data Repository. I'm then  using a parallel stream to map the entities to different ones. 
I can either use a consumer to store those new entities in another repository one by one or collect them into a List and store that in a single bulk operation.
The first is costly while the later might exceed the available memory.

Is there a good way to collect a certain amount of elements in the stream (like limit does), consume that chunk, and keep on going in parallel until all elements are processed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Stream with batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641383/java-8-stream-with-batch-processing)

Answer (score 21):

My approach to bulk operations with chunking is to use a partitioning spliterator wrapper, and another wrapper which overrides the default splitting policy (arithmetic progression of batch sizes in increments of 1024) to simple fixed-batch splitting. Use it like this:

```
Stream<OriginalType> existingStream = ...;
Stream<List<OriginalType>> partitioned = partition(existingStream, 100, 1);
partitioned.forEach(chunk -> ... process the chunk ...);
```

Here is the full code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class PartitioningSpliterator<E> extends AbstractSpliterator<List<E>>
{
  private final Spliterator<E> spliterator;
  private final int partitionSize;

  public PartitioningSpliterator(Spliterator<E> toWrap, int partitionSize) {
    super(toWrap.estimateSize(), toWrap.characteristics() | Spliterator.NONNULL);
    if (partitionSize <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Partition size must be positive, but was " + partitionSize);
    this.spliterator = toWrap;
    this.partitionSize = partitionSize;
  }

  public static <E> Stream<List<E>> partition(Stream<E> in, int size) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new PartitioningSpliterator(in.spliterator(), size), false);
  }

  public static <E> Stream<List<E>> partition(Stream<E> in, int size, int batchSize) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(
        new FixedBatchSpliterator<>(new PartitioningSpliterator<>(in.spliterator(), size), batchSize), false);
  }

  @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<E>> action) {
    final ArrayList<E> partition = new ArrayList<>(partitionSize);
    while (spliterator.tryAdvance(partition::add) 
           && partition.size() < partitionSize);
    if (partition.isEmpty()) return false;
    action.accept(partition);
    return true;
  }

  @Override public long estimateSize() {
    final long est = spliterator.estimateSize();
    return est == Long.MAX_VALUE? est
         : est / partitionSize + (est % partitionSize > 0? 1 : 0);
  }
}
```

---

```
import static java.util.Spliterators.spliterator;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public abstract class FixedBatchSpliteratorBase<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
  private final int batchSize;
  private final int characteristics;
  private long est;

  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics, int batchSize, long est) {
    characteristics |= ORDERED;
    if ((characteristics & SIZED) != 0) characteristics |= SUBSIZED;
    this.characteristics = characteristics;
    this.batchSize = batchSize;
    this.est = est;
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics, int batchSize) {
    this(characteristics, batchSize, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliteratorBase(int characteristics) {
    this(characteristics, 64, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  }

  @Override public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
    final HoldingConsumer<T> holder = new HoldingConsumer<>();
    if (!tryAdvance(holder)) return null;
    final Object[] a = new Object[batchSize];
    int j = 0;
    do a[j] = holder.value; while (++j < batchSize && tryAdvance(holder));
    if (est != Long.MAX_VALUE) est -= j;
    return spliterator(a, 0, j, characteristics());
  }
  @Override public Comparator<? super T> getComparator() {
    if (hasCharacteristics(SORTED)) return null;
    throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
  @Override public long estimateSize() { return est; }
  @Override public int characteristics() { return characteristics; }

  static final class HoldingConsumer<T> implements Consumer<T> {
    Object value;
    @Override public void accept(T value) { this.value = value; }
  }
}
```

---

```
import static java.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream;

import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FixedBatchSpliterator<T> extends FixedBatchSpliteratorBase<T> {
  private final Spliterator<T> spliterator;

  public FixedBatchSpliterator(Spliterator<T> toWrap, int batchSize, long est) {
    super(toWrap.characteristics(), batchSize, est);
    this.spliterator = toWrap;
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliterator(Spliterator<T> toWrap, int batchSize) {
    this(toWrap, batchSize, toWrap.estimateSize());
  }
  public FixedBatchSpliterator(Spliterator<T> toWrap) {
    this(toWrap, 64, toWrap.estimateSize());
  }

  public static <T> Stream<T> withBatchSize(Stream<T> in, int batchSize) {
    return stream(new FixedBatchSpliterator<>(in.spliterator(), batchSize), true);
  }

  public static <T> FixedBatchSpliterator<T> batchedSpliterator(Spliterator<T> toWrap, int batchSize) {
    return new FixedBatchSpliterator<>(toWrap, batchSize);
  }

  @Override public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    return spliterator.tryAdvance(action);
  }
  @Override public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    spliterator.forEachRemaining(action);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `getComparator()` be defined in `FixedBatchSpliterator` and delegate, i.e: `return spliterator.getComparator();`  ?

Comment: Possibly. The `getComparator()` API remains somewhat of a mystery to me.

Comment: what is the difference between `FixedBatchSpliterator` and `PartitioningSpliterator` ? I don't get the `partition(existingStream, 100, 1)`

Comment: @Titmael `FixedBatchSpliterator` is about non-semantic batching of data delivered to ecah worker thread. The effects of this batching are not visible to user-supplied lambdas. `PartitioningSpliterator`, on the other hand, produces chunks of data explicitly passed to your lambda.

Comment: In my case I need to split my stream in chunks of 500 items, I can use only `PartitioningSpliterator#partition(Stream<E> in, int size)` ?

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to write your own `Collector` that accumulates entities and then performs bulk updates.

The `Collector.accumulator()` method can add the entities to an internal temp cache until the cache grows too large.  When the cache is large enough you can do a bulk store into your other repository.

`Collector.merge()` needs to combine 2 thread's Collector's caches into a single cache (and possibly merge)

Finally, the `Collector.finisher()` method is called when the Stream is done so store anything left in the cache here too.

Since you are already using a parallel stream and seem OK with doing multiple loads at the same time, I assume you have thread safety already handled.

**UPDATE**

My comment regarding thread safety and parallel streams was referring to the actual saving/storing into the repository, not concurrency in your temp collection.

Each Collector should (I think) be run in its own thread. A parallel stream should create multiple collector instances by calling `supplier()` multiple times.  So you can treat a collector instance as single threaded and it should work fine.

For example in the Javadoc for `java.util.IntSummaryStatistics` it says:

> This implementation is not thread safe. However, it is safe to use Collectors.toIntStatistics() on a parallel stream, because the parallel implementation of Stream.collect() provides the necessary partitioning, isolation, and merging of results for safe and efficient parallel execution.

Comment: When filling a concurrency save collection by either using peek() or  Collector.accumulator() I can not safely determine when my cache has reached, say, 1000 entries. I would have to lock the collection, take the count, retrieve all entries if filled to my desired level, and release the collection again. Which will kill parallelism dead. I had hope that there is a _good_ way to do it somewhere hidden in the stream API...

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich I'm not sure you need to worry about that.  Each Collector *should* (I think) be run in its own thread.  A parrallel stream should create multiple collector instances by calling `supplier()` multiple times.  I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom collector to do this elegantly.

Please see my answer to a similar question here:

[Custom batch processing collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641383/java-8-stream-with-batch-processing/39058988#39058988)

Then, you can simply batch process the stream in parallel using the above collector to store the records back in your repository, example usage:

```
List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

int batchSize = 3;
Consumer<List<Integer>> batchProcessor = xs -> repository.save(xs);

input.parallelStream()
     .map(i -> i + 1)
     .collect(StreamUtils.batchCollector(batchSize, batchProcessor));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Test
public void streamTest(){

    Stream<Integer> data = Stream.generate(() -> {
        //Block on IO
        return blockOnIO();
    });


    AtomicInteger countDown = new AtomicInteger(1000);
    final ArrayList[] buffer = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<Integer>()};
    Object syncO = new Object();
    data.parallel().unordered().map(i -> i * 1000).forEach(i->{
        System.out.println(String.format("FE %s %d",Thread.currentThread().getName(), buffer[0].size()));
        int c;
        ArrayList<Integer> export=null;
        synchronized (syncO) {
            c = countDown.addAndGet(-1);
            buffer[0].add(i);
            if (c == 0) {
                export=buffer[0];
                buffer[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                countDown.set(1000);
            }
        }
        if(export !=null){
            sendBatch(export);
        }

    });
    //export any remaining
    sendBatch(buffer[0]);
}

Integer blockOnIO(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
        return Integer.valueOf((int)Math.random()*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

void sendBatch(ArrayList al){
    assert al.size() == 1000;
    System.out.println(String.format("LOAD %s %d",Thread.currentThread().getName(), al.size()));
}
```

This is maybe somewhat old-fashion but should achieve batching with a minimum of locking.

It will produce output as

```
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 996
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5 996
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4 998
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 999
LOAD ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 1000
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6 0
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 2
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7 2
FE ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution by My Library: [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
stream.split(batchSize).parallel(threadNum).map(yourBatchProcessFunction);
```