# Reading chunks of a text file with a Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 has a way to create a Stream from lines of a file. In this case, foreach will step through lines. I have a text file with following format..

```
bunch of lines with text
$$$$
bunch of lines with text
$$$$
```

I need to get each set of lines that goes before `$$$$` into a single element in the Stream.

In other words, I need a Stream of Strings. Each string contains the content that goes before `$$$$`.

What is the best way (with minimum overhead) to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32290278/picking-elements-of-a-list-until-condition-is-met-with-java-8-lambdas or also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746429/limit-a-stream-by-a-predicate

Comment: It does not answer my question..

Comment: Does is have to use Streams?

Comment: Yes. There is a way to do this by creating a spliterator from an iterator. I want to avoid that.

Comment: you need to create a custom `predicate`

Comment: You could probably customize [Maurice Naftalin's `LineSpliterator`](https://github.com/mauricen/masteringlambdas/blob/252e193a39eb2d1338158f824dc14d1daace70f9/src/main/java/org/masteringlambdas/ch5/LineSpliterator.java) to split on `\n$$$$\n`. Note that this [inspired the Java 9 implementation of `Files.lines()`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072773). I thought I had seen it in on SO but could not find it.

Comment: Looks similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26465398/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with a solution that processes the lines lazily. I'm not sure if this is possible.

My solution produces an `ArrayList`. If you have to use a `Stream`, simply call `stream()` on it.

```
public class DelimitedFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = lines(Paths.get("delimited.txt"), "$$$$");
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d:%n%s%n", i, lines.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static List<String> lines(Path path, String delimiter) throws IOException {
        return Files.lines(path)
                .collect(ArrayList::new, new BiConsumer<ArrayList<String>, String>() {
                    boolean add = true;

                    @Override
                    public void accept(ArrayList<String> lines, String line) {
                        if (delimiter.equals(line)) {
                            add = true;
                        } else {
                            if (add) {
                                lines.add(line);
                                add = false;
                            } else {
                                int i = lines.size() - 1;
                                lines.set(i, lines.get(i) + '\n' + line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, ArrayList::addAll);
    }
}
```

File content:

```
bunch of lines with text
bunch of lines with text2
bunch of lines with text3
$$$$
2bunch of lines with text
2bunch of lines with text2
$$$$
3bunch of lines with text
3bunch of lines with text2
3bunch of lines with text3
3bunch of lines with text4
$$$$
```

Output:

```
0:
bunch of lines with text
bunch of lines with text2
bunch of lines with text3
1:
2bunch of lines with text
2bunch of lines with text2
2:
3bunch of lines with text
3bunch of lines with text2
3bunch of lines with text3
3bunch of lines with text4
```

---

**Edit:**

I've finally come up with a solution which lazily generates the `Stream`:

```
public static Stream<String> lines(Path path, String delimiter) throws IOException {
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
    Iterator<String> iterator = lines.iterator();
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<String>() {
        String nextLine;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (nextLine != null) {
                return true;
            }
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String line = iterator.next();
                if (!delimiter.equals(line)) {
                    nextLine = line;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            lines.close();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(nextLine);
            nextLine = null;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String line = iterator.next();
                if (delimiter.equals(line)) {
                    break;
                }
                sb.append('\n').append(line);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), false);
}
```

This is actually/coincidentally very similar to the implementation of [`BufferedReader.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) (which is internally used by [`Files.lines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)). It may be less overhead not to use both of these methods but instead use [`Files.newBufferedReader(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) directly.

Comment: This works. This is similar to what I mentioned in my fourth comment under the question. Can you please delete the ArrayList based answer and include the best performant version of your second code so that I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scanner` as an iterator and create the stream from it:

```
private static Stream<String> recordStreamOf(Readable source) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source);
    scanner.useDelimiter("$$$$");
    return StreamSupport
        .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(scanner, Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.NONNULL), false)
        .onClose(scanner::close);
}
```

This will preserve the newlines in the chunks for further filtering or splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            list = stream
                .filter(line -> !line.equals("$$$$"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That does not combine the lines between the "$$$$" lines to a single element. Rather it removes these delimeters, leaving you clueless afterwards.

Comment: I realised it afterwards but I'm not able to remove my answer. You can concatenate the lines and split with $$$$.

Comment: @Isukthar you should be able to remove it by using the link at the bottom left of your answer

Comment: I got the message "An error has occurred - please retry your request." when i click on delete.

Comment: It might be a temporary issue, otherwise don't hesitate to ask for help on [meta].

Answer (score 0):

There already exists a similar shorter answer, but type.safe is the following, without extra state:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("... .txt");
    try {
        List<StringBuilder> glist = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .collect(() -> new ArrayList<StringBuilder>(),
                        (list, line) -> {
                            if (list.isEmpty() || list.get(list.size() - 1).toString().endsWith("$$$$\n")) {
                                list.add(new StringBuilder());
                            }
                            list.get(list.size() - 1).append(line).append('\n');
                        },
                        (list1, list2) -> {
                            if (!list1.isEmpty() && !list1.get(list1.size() - 1).toString().endsWith("$$$$\n")
                                    && !list2.isEmpty()) {
                                // Merge last of list1 and first of list2:
                                list1.get(list1.size() - 1).append(list2.remove(0).toString());
                            }
                            list1.addAll(list2);
                        });
        glist.forEach(sb -> System.out.printf("------------------%n%s%n", sb));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Instead of `.endsWith("$$$$\n")` it would be better to do:

```
.matches("(^|\n)\\$\\$\\$\\$\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution based on [this previous work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465398/2711488):

```
public class ChunkSpliterator extends Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<List<String>> {
    private final Spliterator<String> source;
    private final Predicate<String> delimiter;
    private final Consumer<String> getChunk;
    private List<String> current;

    ChunkSpliterator(Spliterator<String> lineSpliterator, Predicate<String> mark) {
        super(lineSpliterator.estimateSize(), ORDERED|NONNULL);
        source=lineSpliterator;
        delimiter=mark;
        getChunk=s -> {
            if(current==null) current=new ArrayList<>();
            current.add(s);
        };
    }
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<String>> action) {
        while(current==null || !delimiter.test(current.get(current.size()-1)))
            if(!source.tryAdvance(getChunk)) return lastChunk(action);
        current.remove(current.size()-1);
        action.accept(current);
        current=null;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean lastChunk(Consumer<? super List<String>> action) {
        if(current==null) return false;
        action.accept(current);
        current=null;
        return true;
    }

    public static Stream<List<String>> toChunks(
        Stream<String> lines, Predicate<String> splitAt, boolean parallel) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(
            new ChunkSpliterator(lines.spliterator(), splitAt),
            parallel);
    }
}
```

which you can use like

```
try(Stream<String> lines=Files.lines(pathToYourFile)) {
    ChunkSpliterator.toChunks(
        lines,
        Pattern.compile("^\\Q$$$$\\E$").asPredicate(),
        false)
    /* chain your stream operations, e.g.
    .forEach(s -> { s.forEach(System.out::print); System.out.println(); })
     */;
}
```