# How to read a file simultaneously using three threads in java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

My program is as below:

```
import java.io.*;
class MyThread implements Runnable{
    int st,en;
    LineNumberReader lmr1;
    BufferedWriter bw;
        MyThread(int s,int e){
        st=s;
        en=e;
    } 
    public void run(){

        try{

                bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("EmpWritten.txt"));
                            lmr1=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("out3.txt"));
                String s=Thread.currentThread().getName();
                            lmr1.skip(st);
                while(st++<en){
                        bw.write(s+"\t"+lmr1.readLine());
                        bw.newLine();

                }
            lmr1.close();
            bw.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

}
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        LineNumberReader lmr=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("out3.txt"));
        lmr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        int num=lmr.getLineNumber();
        int num1=num/3,num2=2*num1;

        MyThread mt1=new MyThread(0,num1);
        MyThread mt2=new MyThread(num1+1,num2);
        MyThread mt3=new MyThread(num2+1,num);

        Thread t1=new Thread(mt1);
        Thread t2=new Thread(mt2);
        Thread t3=new Thread(mt3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start(); 


        lmr.close();
    }
}
```

Input:

> Commit ID  Name    Salary Department Number 
>  Commit
>   ID1   Name1   25100   Dept1
>  Commit ID2    Name2   25200   Dept2
>  Commit
>   ID3   Name3   25300   Dept3
>  Commit ID4    Name4   25400   Dept4
>  Commit
>   ID5   Name5   25500   Dept5
>  Commit ID6    Name6   25600   Dept6
>  Commit
>   ID7   Name7   25700   Dept7
>  Commit ID8    Name8   25800   Dept8
>  Commit
>   ID9   Name9   25900   Dept9
>  Commit ID10   Name10  26000   Dept10

output:

> Thread-2  ID   Name    Salary Department Number
>  Thread-2  Commit
>   ID1   Name1   25100   Dept1
>  Thread-2  Commit ID2  Name2   25200   Dept2
>   Thread-2  Commit ID3  Name3   25300   Dept3

Why don't other threads execute?What modifications need to be done to get the desired output?Efficient implementations of the program is also welcome.

Comment: Why do you think they don't execute? Each thread writes to the same file, so all you see is the output of the last thread to write, which overwrites the output of the previous ones. You're also ignoring exceptions, so if one thread fails to do anything, you can't be aware of it. Don't ever do that.

Comment: That's a backwards approach to performance. If you want to leverage all your cores while using sequential file reading, then use one thread dedicated to reading and dispatch work to several worker threads.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you tell how to do that?

Comment: Read lines in chunks of such size that their processing takes at least 10 milliseconds; for each chunk submit a task to an ExecutorService. You'll still need to work out how to collect all the results in order.

Comment: Or use the Streams APi to get most of the parallelization concerns solved out of the box. Check out https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408350/is-there-a-good-way-to-extract-chunks-of-data-from-a-java-8-stream

Answer (score 0):

Three threads worked.
You can see it after adding some logs in your run method.
I am not sure what you want exactly.
But I think you need producer-consumer design pattern.