# How to iterate over every n elements with java?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method named calculate and it takes too long to complete. So I decided to send my info list objects to this method partially. How can I iterate over every n elements?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Map<String, Long> info....;  //my info Map

    //I want to call method like 
    for(int i = 0; i<info.size(); i+=5)
       calculate(info.submap(i,i+5)); 
}


public static boolean calculate(Map<String, Long> info){
    //Some calculations

}
```

Comment: You are just adding and removing the stackframe `info.size()/5` times.

Comment: I just want to send info objects 5 by 5 to calculate method. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: in java8 you can use parallel stream

Comment: @hellzone: i meant that by sending it partially in this way you are not gaining anything in terms of time performance.

Comment: @Azodious calculate method sends this list to a web service and there is a problem with this webservice. When I sent 100 info, it responses nearly after 1 hour and when I sent 5 info it responses in 1 second.

Comment: Parallel Stream is a good suggestion then, by Jobin. Check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375176/should-i-always-use-a-parallel-stream-when-possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
class SomeClass {

    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 5;    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> info = new HashMap<>();

        LongStream.range(0, 30).boxed().forEach(i -> info.put("key" + i, i)); // for test

        IntStream.range(0, info.size() / BUFFER_SIZE)
                .boxed()
                .parallel()
                .map(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(info.keySet().toArray(), BUFFER_SIZE * i, BUFFER_SIZE * (i + 1)))
                .map(Arrays::asList)
                .map(keys -> info.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(x -> keys.contains(x.getKey()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))
                .forEach(SomeClass::calculate);
    }

    public static boolean calculate(Map<String, Long> info) {
        System.out.println("calculation for " + info.toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is to implement a sort of [batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) for the data represented by your `Map<String, Long> info` instance. You can then create a [generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) for these batches as a `Stream`: This is in a way the inverse of the [`Stream.flatMap(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) family of methods, but, ironically, [there doesn't seem to be any idiomatic functional way of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25408350/1391325) and so you may have to create the batches yourself in an imperative manner — for example:

```
private static <T> Stream<Stream<T>> createBatchStreams(final Iterator<T> iter, final int maxBatchSize) {
    final Stream.Builder<Stream<T>> resultBuilder = Stream.builder();
    {
        // NOTE: This logic could also be encapsulated in a Collector class
        // in order to make it less imperative style
        Stream.Builder<T> currentBatchBuilder = Stream.builder();
        int currentBatchSize = 0;

        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            final T next = iter.next();
            if (currentBatchSize == maxBatchSize) {
                resultBuilder.add(currentBatchBuilder.build());
                // Start building a new batch
                currentBatchBuilder = Stream.builder();
                currentBatchSize = 0;
            }
            currentBatchBuilder.add(next);
            currentBatchSize++;
        }
        // Check if there is a non-empty Stream to add (e.g. if there was a
        // final batch which was smaller than the others)
        if (currentBatchSize > 0) {
            resultBuilder.add(currentBatchBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    return resultBuilder.build();
}
```

Using this method, you can then create a generator of batches of your map data, which can then be fed to your `calculate(...)` function (albeit with a slightly different signature):

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Map<String, Long> info = LongStream.range(0, 10).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(value -> "key" + value, Function.identity())); // Test data
    final Stream<Stream<Entry<String, Long>>> batches = createBatchStreams(info.entrySet().iterator(), 5);
    batches.forEach(batch -> {
        calculate(batch);
        // Do some other stuff after processing each batch
    });
}

private static boolean calculate(final Stream<Entry<String, Long>> info) {
    // Some calculations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop n-times over the collection and take the range of items you need.

```
         final int AMOUNT_OF_ITEMS_IN_BATCH = 200;
        List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();//TODO YOUR LIST WITH OBJECTS TO SPLIT UP AND PROCESS IN ITERATIONS
        int loops = IntMath.divide(objects.size(), AMOUNT_OF_ITEMS_IN_BATCH, RoundingMode.CEILING);

        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            Set<Object> nextBatch = objects.stream()
                    .skip(i * AMOUNT_OF_ITEMS_IN_BATCH)
                    .limit(AMOUNT_OF_ITEMS_IN_BATCH)
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

           //TODO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WITH TE SUBLIST 
        }
```